# Change Button Label with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, button

I was working to change the label of the button with javascript. The button is using a class but not ID. what js method will applicable?

I tried through getElementsByClassName but this not worked

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="window_open">Submit</button>
```

JS Code:

```
var status="Newlabel";
document.getElementsByClassName("window_open").innerHTML=status;
```

I expect the output of Newlabel but there is no result

Comment: Hint: `document.getElementsByClassName` is capable of returning multiple elements.

Comment: use `document.querySelector(".window_open").innerHTML=status;` instead, `getElementsByClassName` returns an `Array`

Comment: Try `document.querySelector('button[type="button"].window_open')` to get the first element that matches that selector.

Comment: @ajaiJothi It returns an `HTMLCollection`, actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object, you need the first item `[0]`:

```js
var status = "Newlabel";
document.getElementsByClassName("window_open")[0].innerHTML = status;
```

```html
<button type="button" class="window_open">Submit</button>
```